# nodejs mongodb insertMany throws duplicate error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs and the official mongo driver (3.5.5), I have a collection with 2 indexes on the _id field (one simple equal to one and one hashed)

I have the following code in my node where in a loop, at each iteration, I make a insertMany operation. In the insertMany, I do not specify the _id property of any object, but when running the script, at one moment (at any random iteration) the code throws an exception cause the insertMany try to insert a duplicate key on the _id field, but I don't understand why, as I don't specify any _id, so mongo will normally generate a new one at each insert no?

this is the exception :

```
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mycollection index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5ede6a9f8742b3001fe79378') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (/usr/share/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1112:11)
    at resultHandler (/usr/share/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:501:23)
    at handler (/usr/share/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:973:24)
    at wireProtocol.(anonymous function) (/usr/share/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:437:5)
    at /usr/share/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:420:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg:
   'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mycollection index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId(\'5ede6a9f8742b3001fe79378\') }',
```

Thanks

Comment: Generated ids are not guaranteed to be unique. If you insert more than 16 million documents per second you'll have an id collision. https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst#counter

Comment: Adding on to this D. SM's comment -- if your client _generates_ more than 16 million `_id`s in a second, you'll run into an _id collision. If your code first generates the bulk write operations before executing them, the client will likely create all of the `_id`s in the same second & the collision between those _ids will only surface later.

Comment: is there a way to avoid this issue?